# FME - what is the difference between "generate workspace" and "create workspace"?

Tags: fme-form

as a newbie to FME I can´t really understand the basic difference between the two ways of making a workspace. Generate or Create. Can someone explain the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create Workspace is like a dashboard that allows you to access existing templates, your own saved templates, training, or pre-built demos via FME Store.  Generate Workspace does not have the dashboard option if you do not want to use any of the options listed above.

Answer (score 0):

Also, Generate Workspace is a single dialog. If you go through the Create Workspace wizard, it's the same thing but a series of dialogs. I always recommend Generate Workspace.

Incidentally, the shortcut key is Ctrl+G. The shortcut for Create Workspace is Ctrl+N.